# Toolbar is white when expand

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have got AppBarLayout with Toolbar and CoordinatorLayout.

I have got RecyclerView inside this FrameLayout.

I made TabLayout.setVisibility(GONE);

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorText"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorText"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorText"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My issue is white Toolbar sometimes when its back from top edge.
When white color is appear and I drag more down it is back to normal Toolbar color.

I don't know where is problem.

[image]

Comment: which version of support library are you using?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with the new v 23.0.0 library. If you use v 22.2.1 or lower you wont have that issue.